# PFFile to UIImage in Parse (ios)

Tags: ios, image, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to convert a PFFile to a UIImage.  It works, however, it doesn't seem to run until the very end.  The line after the image is called appends the image to the array (photosArray.append(image!)), but when I do this, it doesnt work, and stores nothing.  I believe this is because since the image hasnt been fully retrieved yet because it is grabbing the image in the background.  How do I not have it save in the background, but wait until all the data is loaded, THEN append to the photosArray image, so the array isnt empty?

```
var photosArray = [UIImage]()
let photosValue = log["Images"] as! PFFile
    photosValue.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                //line below appends nothing!  photosArray is an empty array, []
                photosArray.append(image!)
                //following line of code doesnt run until the end.  Is the last line to be printed in console.
                println("Our Image: \(image)")
            }
    })
    //prints "[]", no value
    println(photosArray)
    println("Our Image Array^^")

}

//after all the code is ran, the println("Our Image: \(image)") will run, 
//and say "Our Image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x16f0ead0>, {394, 256})".
//This is the last line of the console logged, so it IS saving, but not until the end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a correct assumption, the whole point of the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock is to handle the response data. You also wouldn't be able to assign

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
```

if it were nil.

I'm not sure about what println statements you're referring to, however printing out the array while data is still being collected in the background may not give you a result, and just

```
[]
```

But you should see

```
println("Our image: \(image)")
```

If you plan to display these images inside a UIImageView I suggest taking a look at the ParseUI class PFImageView, which has a property you can assign a PFFile to and then a method in which to load it.

Comment: You are right.  The image still populated the View Controller.  Guess I shouldn't rely on the println 100% of the time lol.

Comment: lol, it's the Parse background thread, at first it feels strange but the flow will become 2nd nature soon enough.